# Save a workshared model as a cloud model to BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Is it possible to save a workshared model to BIM360 as a workshared cloud model using Revit API and/or Forge API ?

I have multiple models that I wish to upload on BIM360, but from what I see the `SaveAsCloudModel` method that is currently available in Revit 2021 API and described in this [post](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/revit-2021-cloud-model-api.html#4.5) only works with non-workshared models. Is there any other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Revit API Docs](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/news?section=toc10), this functionality has been added in Revit 2022 API

> SaveAsCloudModel() now supports save of a new Revit Cloud Worksharing central model
> The method:
>
> Document.SaveAsCloudModel(Guid, Guid, String, String)
> has been enhanced to support upload of ***local workshared file*** into BIM 360 Design as a Revit Cloud Worksharing central model.
>
> In addition, the exception UnauthenticatedUserException is removed from the documented exceptions for this method.

#### Additional References

Similar question in Autodesk forum: [Initiate cloud collaboration for a workshared model](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/initiate-cloud-collaboration-for-a-workshared-model/td-p/10113202)

Answer (score 1):

The `SaveAsCloudModel` function is available since Revit 2019.2, and you can follow my code snippet shared here to activate the cloud worksharing:

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/11/initiating-bim360-collaboration-and-linking.html

BTW, you need to install the Revit 2019.2 service package before coding.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is good for saving a nonworkshared model as a cloud model and enabling worksharing afterwards. Unfortunately I was looking for a way to save a central model which already has worksharing activated, but this is not yet possible with the `SaveAsCloudModel` method as specified in the Revit API (Saves current nonworkshared model as a cloud model in BIM 360.).